# Reading code from GitHub as text (raw) in a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to read some source code (C language) from my GitHub repository to be shown as text in my webpage. I can access the code in raw mode through https://raw.github.com.

I'm using jQuery GET function to read the data but it doesn't work. Problem is related with XMLHttpRequest and Access-Control-Allow-Origin but, despite I found some related question on stackoverflow ([XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)) it didn't work for me. I tried everything.

My jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'https://raw.github.com/raysan5/raylib/master/examples/ex01_basic_window.c';

    $.get(url, function(data) { 
        $('#code').text(data);
      }, 'text');
    });
</script>
```

Please, could someone help me with this issue? Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2013: You could try and delete the dot between raw and github:

```
https://rawgithub.com/raysan5/raylib/master/examples/ex01_basic_window.c
```

See [rawgithub.com](https://rawgithub.com/), also explained in this [blog post](http://geekdave.com/2013/06/19/linking-raw-github-files-from-jsfiddle/):

> GitHub discourages this, since they want repo owners to use Github Pages to host specific versions of their files. They discourage it by serving files from the “`raw`” domain with `Content-Type: text/plain` instead of `Content-type:application/javascript`.
>
> This wasn’t a problem until recently, when Google Chrome implemented a security fix that prevents JavaScript from being executed if it has an incorrect `Content-type`.
> This makes sense when you’re viewing pages outside of your control. But when it’s you who’s deciding what scripts to include, it’s a hassle.

As [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161677/reading-code-from-github-as-text-raw-in-a-web-page/20161818#comment30053868_20161818):

> It's worth mentioning that **the only reason that this web service solves the OP's problem is that it includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header**.

---

OCt. 2018: As seen in [their homepage](https://web.archive.org/web/20230406204829/https://rawgit.com/)

> ### RawGit has reached the end of its useful life
>
> RawGit is now in a sunset phase and will soon shut down. It's been a fun five years, but all things must end.
>
> GitHub repositories that served content through RawGit within the last month will continue to be served until at least October of 2019. URLs for other repositories are no longer being served.

His creator, Ryan Grove, said [Aug. 5th, 2023](https://pie.gd/@yaypie/110835141649693917):

> About 5 years ago I put RawGit into “sunset” mode. I generated a bloom filter representing every repo URL that had been active within the last month, deployed a change to only serve requests for those repos, resolved to let it keep running until it broke, and then never looked at it again except to renew the domain from time to time.
>
> Checked on it today and it’s still running fine, serving 393 million requests and 4.1 TB of data a month with literally zero maintenance. ‍♂️

Comment: Nice. It's worth mentioning that the only reason that this web service solves the OP's problem is that it includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header.

Comment: @RobW Good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @RobW I also tried adding <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*"> in my webpage header but I imagine it must be in the server side not in my webpage...

Comment: out of date? apparently rawgithub is no longer a thing?

Comment: @starball True, but it was the right answer 10 years ago when the OP asked their question ;)

Comment: @starball I have edited the answer to mention the 2028 sunset, but also to explain why some rawgithub URLs are *still* served to this day (2023).