# Include code from GitHub as code block in GitBook

Tags: javascript, github, gitbook

How can I display raw code like this in GitBook?

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luyongxu/SignalPlot/master/Code/1.016%20Asset%20Bubbles.R
```

I believe this is related to:
[Reading code from GitHub as text (raw) in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161677/reading-code-from-github-as-text-raw-in-a-web-page)
But I don't know how to call the JavaScript function in the main document.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `book.json` file to your GitBook. Paste this into it:

```
{
    "plugins": ["github-embed"]
}
```

Now just put something like this in your page:

```
{% github_embed "https://github.com/v5analytics/gitbook-plugin-github-embed/blob/1cd16ac/index.js#L3-L8" %}{% endgithub_embed %}
```

It's that simple!

[Here's some documentation.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitbook-plugin-github-embed)

Note: I've got it working locally (using `gitbook install` and `gitbook serve`), but it's not working for me on GitBooks, so I've filed an issue [here](https://github.com/visallo/gitbook-plugin-github-embed/issues) and [here](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook/issues/1797).

(proof it's working locally)
[image]

Apologies on behalf of gitbook-plugin-github-embed for their deprecated code!

Comment: Thank you! I tried this (using GitBook Editor on a Mac), but nothing appears. In the console it says: "Error: HTML and templating tags are not yet supported in document mode." I guess I'll simply have to wait until this is fully developed. I also experimented with JavaScript plug-ins (such as menus etc.) but most of them do not work consistently over Safari, Firefox, Chrome etc.